# How to map @Version with @JoinTable annotation

Tags: hibernate, version-control, annotations

I have one mapping table Say `EMP_ADD` which maintains mapping between `EMPLOYEE` and `ADDRESS` tables.
Now to do this mapping I use following mapping in `Employee` class

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name="EMP_ADD", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="emp_id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="add_id")})
List<Address> lstAdd;
```

And in `Address` class

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinTable(name="EMP_ADD", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="add_id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="emp_id")})
Employee objEmp;
```

Now I have created one more column in `EMP_ADD` which is `version_number` which use to handle row version while updating record.
As we can see that there is no any pojo for `EMP_ADD` so I can't use `@Version` annotation.
Can any know how to handle version in `@JoinTable` ?

Comment: Your mapping is wrong. In a bidirectional OneToMany association, the one side MUST be marked as the inverse side of the many side using the mappedBy attribute (and thus must not define a JoinTable). Since the association is bidirectional, why don't you simply use a join column in address?

Comment: I can't use join column in address B'Coz above three tables are historical and my client want me to use existing structure only.